# Form submitting duplicate entree's to mySQL and two emails with php function mail()

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, email

I have a simple php page that contains a form. When submitted it should send 2 emails(one to me and one to my boss), and insert its data into my database. Instead its sending 4 emails (two to me and two to my boss) and inserting 2 rows of identical data instead of one. Any idea why this might be happening?

EDIT: I've found that the problem only occurs when you refresh the page, and each time you refresh the page it sends out a new copy of the email/data.

Here's my PHP (if you see removed I removed what was in the quotation marks for security reasons)

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    define('DB_NAME', 'removed');
    define('DB_USER', 'removed');
    define('DB_PW', 'removed');
    define('DB_HOST', 'removed');

    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_NAME);

    if(!$link){
        die('Test Connection Failed 1: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    //Name
    $FName = $_POST['FName'];
    $FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $FName);
    $LName = $_POST['LName'];
    $LName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $LName);
    $Company = $_POST['Company'];
    $Company = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Company);

    //Phone
    $Phone1 = $_POST['Phone1'];
    $Fax = $_POST['Fax'];

    //Address
    $Street = $_POST['Street'];
    $Street = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Street);
    $City = $_POST['City'];
    $City = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $City);
    $State = $_POST['State'];
    $State = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $State);
    $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
    $Zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Zip);
    $Country = $_POST['Country'];
    $Country = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Country);

    //Message
    $Message = $_POST['Message'];
    $Message = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Message);

    //Email
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email);

        //Email
    $Email2 = $_POST['Email2'];
    $Email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email);


    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `removed`.`removed`(`ID`, `FName`, `LName`, `Company`, `Phone`, `Fax`, `Street`, `City`, `State`, `Country`, `Zipcode`, `Email`, `Message`) VALUES (NULL, '".$FName."', '".$LName."', '".$Company."', '".$Phone1."', '".$Fax."', '".$Street."', '".$City."', '".$State."', '".$Country."', '".$Zipcode."', '".$Email."', '".$Message."')";

    if(!mysqli_real_query($link, $sqlInsert)){
        echo "Failed To Post To Database";
    } else {
        mysqli_close($link);    
    }

    //Validate first
    if(empty($LName)||empty($Email)) 
    {
        echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
        exit;
    }

    $email_from = $Email;
    $email_subject = "Bel Air Contact Form";
    $email_body = '<html><body>';
    $email_body .= '<table border="1" cellpadding="15">';
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $FName . " " . $LName . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>Company:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $Company . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>Email Address:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $Email . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>Secondary Email Address:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $Email2 . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>Street:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $Street . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>City:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $City . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>State:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $State . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>Country:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $Country . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>Zipcode:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $Zipcode . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $Phone1 . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='150px'><strong>Fax:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66CCFF' width='400px'>" . $Fax . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='150px'><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td bgcolor='#66FFFF' width='400px'>" . $Message . "</td></tr>";
    $email_body .= "</table>";
    $email_body .= "</body></html>";

    $rbailey = "removed";
    $info = "removed";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $Email \r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($rbailey,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    mail($info,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

} //End of ISSET if statement

?>
```

If needed I can include the form but its a very basic form with a ton of fields so I left it out so my post isn't insanely long.

Comment: How are you submitting the postdata to the server?

Comment: <li class="buttons">
     <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="952735" />       
     <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit" />
</li>

Comment: For one thing `$Email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email);` should be `$Email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Email2);`

Comment: Sidenote: Just to save you quite a few keystrokes; you can just do `$FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['FName']);` etc. rather than defining twice.

Comment: You're also missing a dot in `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` which should read as `$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` that alone will break your headers and could be part of the problem, or "the" problem.

Comment: I fixed both those issues and while they didn't fix "the" problem thanks for pointing those out! I figured out that the issues comes when refreshing the page, each time you refresh the page it sends another copy of the emails / data out. Any idea why?

Comment: Simple: Use a header after your last `mail()` to redirect to a page on your website. Done deal. ;-) and possibly add something to your form that it needs revalidation and clears the form elements if someone tries to click back. Let me know if you want that as an answer, including what I've said earlier.

Comment: I was anticipating to place an answer myself along with everything else I wrote to help fix your code. I'll just post it, since I already wrote it all out lol

Comment: Yeah I see that now I've deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: Thank you Timothy. I've added a few things in my answer in an edit, if you haven't seen them since you last saw my original answer. This in regards to a link to preventing multiple submissions using sessions and tokens which works very well. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, you have a missing dot in one of your headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
         ^
```

That alone will break your headers.

The issue appears to be due to a page refresh.

To remedy this, add a [**header**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) after your last `mail()` call, and make sure you're not outputting before header.

I.e.:

```
mail($info,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
exit;
```

In your form, add `autocomplete="off"` in your form, and/or your input fields.

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Which is useful in HTML5 to clear any previously entered contents in a form.

- You can also use sessions and tokens.

Here is a link you can consult:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Sidenote:

Just to save you quite a few keystrokes; you can just do:

```
$FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['FName']);
```

etc. rather than defining everything twice.